# how to write chainer Iterator has the ability the same as MultiprocessIterator functionality

Tags: chainer

I want to write the RNN/LSTM iterator the same as https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/recurrentnet.html example, but add multi process fetch ability the same as MultiprocessIterator functionality.
The url link's example as following:

```
from __future__ import division

class ParallelSequentialIterator(chainer.dataset.Iterator):
    def __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, repeat=True):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.epoch = 0
        self.is_new_epoch = False
        self.repeat = repeat
        self.offsets = [i * len(dataset) // batch_size for i in range(batch_size)]
        self.iteration = 0

    def __next__(self):
        length = len(self.dataset)
        if not self.repeat and self.iteration * self.batch_size >= length:
            raise StopIteration
        cur_words = self.get_words()
        self.iteration += 1
        next_words = self.get_words()

        epoch = self.iteration * self.batch_size // length
        self.is_new_epoch = self.epoch < epoch
        if self.is_new_epoch:
            self.epoch = epoch

        return list(zip(cur_words, next_words))

    @property
    def epoch_detail(self):
        return self.iteration * self.batch_size / len(self.dataset)

    def get_words(self):
        return [self.dataset[(offset + self.iteration) % len(self.dataset)]
                for offset in self.offsets]

    def serialize(self, serializer):
        self.iteration = serializer('iteration', self.iteration)
        self.epoch = serializer('epoch', self.epoch)

train_iter = ParallelSequentialIterator(train, 20)
val_iter = ParallelSequentialIterator(val, 1, repeat=False)
```

Comment: How about try overriding MultiProcessIterator instead of Iterator in your custom iterator class, and override _get function to prepare the batch?

Comment: I suspect MultiProcessIterator  has bug inside it, And in RNN, the mini-batch must have an sequence order in order to use LSTM to train.
so maybe using MultiProcessIterator can induce trouble?

Comment: I am currently using from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager to write an myself define ParallelRNNIterator, do you have any more proposal?

Comment: because each sequence has different length across time axis, maybe it is better to use bucket and padding strategy. this code must be a little more complicated.

Comment: What is _get function in MultiProcessIterator ? Can you give me more information?